# connection to smtp.gmail.com using telnet gives syntax error

Tags: smtp, gmail, telnet, smtp-auth

I have established a connection to smtp.gmail.com using telnet and have been able to log in with AUTH LOGIN. After this I tried the command `MAIL FROM: <example@gmail.com>`. But it gave me a syntax error. I have tried without the brackets and without capitals. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

Try without space between "MAIL FROM:" and email address.

**Simple Mail Transfer Protocol**
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321

```
MAIL FROM:<userx@y.foo.org>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right telnet to gmail on port 25 will not authenticate you need to use port 587
also if you are doing this already leave 2 spaces between FROM: and me@gmail.com eg

```
`MAIL FROM:  me@gmail.com`
```

Answer (score 0):

Late reply. I had the exact same problem, and the above answer about "try without space" partly solved it, but was not enough on its own.

What worked for me was:

- no space between mail from: and address
- angle brackets around email address

For example,

```
mail from:<someone@somedomain.com.au>
```